# copyTo with lastCol and lastRow behaving unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on a submission form for a database and can't seem to work out how to get it to copy these blocks individually. [I've got a link to a sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UnbrG39sXeOSxZWMsI-h5Z03fIhqsxh27hwF86HYBzY/edit?usp=sharing) and a code snippet. The first block of code that copies the first block works as expected, it copies, finds the last column, and pastes into the next.

The second block pastes in the correct column but seems like its grabbing the lastRow from the first column, which is filled with headers. It should be pasting the second block directly under the first and to the best of my knowledge, the code says it should too.

Anyone able to help me understand what's going on here? I have a few more blocks that'll need to be pasted over as well.

```
 function Submit() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const dataSh = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Data");
  const sumbmitSh = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Submit");

//copies first block
  var lastCol = dataSh.getLastColumn();
    sumbmitSh.getRange("C3:C6").copyTo(dataSh.getRange(1,lastCol+1),{contentsOnly:true});

//copies second block
  var lastCol = dataSh.getLastColumn();
  var lastRow = dataSh.getLastRow();
    sumbmitSh.getRange("F3:F7").copyTo(dataSh.getRange(lastRow,lastCol),{contentsOnly:true});
```

Thanks heaps for any info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine for me.

[image]

You can add `flush` after the first `copyTo` to make sure the data is read again with the new column positions.

```
   ...
     .copyTo(dataSh.getRange(1,lastCol+1)  ...
   SpreadsheetApp.flush();
```